# How to prevent chromeipass from auto-filling credentials?

Tags: password-management, chrome, keepass

ChromeIPass (addon for Keepass on Chrome) wants to unlock the database every time it detects credential fields, even if I don't even have an account on that site. This is the default setting (october 2015).

Is it possible to only unlock the database on my request (by clicking on the ChromeIPass button)? 
Is it possible to keep the KeePass database encrypted and only unlock it when required?

This question is security related as any workaround not carefully thought through can increase the security risk.

Basic (bad) workarounds could be:

- keep your DB open at all times when using Chrome
- try a custom reconfiguration of ChromeIPass (with the risk to reduce the security level)*.
- stop using ChromeIPass and return to your old way to manage your access (copy/paste credentials??) because this issue is very frustrating.

*official mention from the ChromeIPass setting page:

> Attention! Please change the following settings only if you know what
>   you are doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to only unlock the database on my request (by clicking
>   on the ChromeIPass button)? Is it possible to keep the KeePass
>   database encrypted and only unlock it when required?

Yes it is. ChromeIPass requires the Keepass extension **KeePassHttp**. The default settings can be really annoying if you are used to keep your DB locked most of the time (DB is opened manually and only when required):

- Open Keepass and go on the Interface tab options  (Tools > KeePass Http Options).
- unecheck "Request for unlocking the database if it is locked"

Save and you are done. Now ChromeIPass won't try to open automatically  your Keepass DB.

**Suggestions**

Then to quickly open Keepass manually you can use the Keepass Global shortcut (available by default) or you can simply click the ChromeIPass button.

Global shortcut:

- `CTRL+ALT+A` this will open a window with a list of entries that matched or
- `CTRL+ALT+K` to simply open keepass and search your entry.

You may also like to see a dropdown that will suggest you automatically the logins available. Make you sure you have checked the following option in ChromeIPass:

- [x] Activate autocomplete for username fields.

note: to see the dropdown list your Keepass DB must be unlocked.

Here are other suggestions for better experience with Keepass and ChromeIPass. Disable any autocomplete feature and try to use the Global Keepass shortcut instead. Don't let ChromeIPass think for you.

ChromeIPass settings:

- [  ] activate password generator (can be done direclty in keepass)
- [  ] automatically fill-in single credentials entry (too risky)
- [x] activate autocomplete for username fields
- [  ] auto fill HTTP Auth dialog and send them.

note: This is working for Keepass V2.

Comment: That's the sort of answer I've been looking for. Thanks a lot for the detailed description! I had to manually add the shortcut to my Ubuntu shortcut settings though, as described on the setup page of KeePass (http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html) under **Global Auto-Type**, but that was not a big deal.